# How to apply animation only for parent view?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm using Relative Layout as parent view & Text View as its child.. I'm applying animation(zoom out effect) to parent view, but it is applying on its child text view also. I want to apply its animation effect only for parent view

This is my code in adapters getView() method :

parentView = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rel_lt);

Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.zoom_out);
parentView.setAnimation(animation);

Comment: Can you please check following link will resolve your need? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677652/android-playing-animation-only-on-parent-view

Comment: Hey Kevin I tried that link before but that one is different from which I looking for. That one is Rotation effect & I looking for zoom out effect on view background only..

Comment: Okie then you try creating a ParentLayout, inside that create one more layout with match_parent to previous layout. and not again inside parent layout add your child view and give animation to second layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use this layout for your animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_lt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#FF890009" >
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> **Dont apply animation to root RelativeLayout. Apply animation only to the child RelativeLayout with id @+id/rel_lt.**

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@_id/parent_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/child_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**Now try giving animation to child_view and see!** Hope this helps you

Comment: Thats great @ShekharMangarule. Keep Going! Kindly accept useful answer for future references!